# Is there a shortcut to access the Windows Taskbar programs beyond the 10th one?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar, shortcuts, hotkeys

In Windows there is the hotkey Win + 1-0 to access the programs you have set in your taskbar, numbering from 1 up to the 10th one. Is there a shortcut to access the programs in your taskbar beyond the 10th?

Answer (score 0):

Try this : https://hyperkeys.xureilab.com

Not exactly what you're looking for : You can assign shortcuts to pin a window then bring it back later.

For example, I'm pinning my browser with ALT+SHIFT+A and bring it back with ALT+A.
Same for Z, E, R etc (I have an azerty keyboard).